# C# Moq unable to return correct value

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I am creating a Mock object to mock a method call that should return 1 using Moq in an MSTest unit test project to test an azure function.

My Interface -

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    public int UpdateDB(MyClass obj);
}
```

My Class method implementation -

```
public int UpdateDB(MyClass obj)
{
    try
    {
        int i = 0;
        using (var db = dbContext)
        {
            db.myClassEntitity.Add(obj);
            i = db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return i;
    }
    //catch block
}
```

Calling the method in  my azure function-

```
int rows = _dataUpdater.UpdateDB(obj);
```

Mocking code in my test project -

```
private readonly Mock<IMyInterface> _dbUpdater = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
_dbUpdater.Setup(p => p.UpdateDB(obj)).Returns(1);
```

My issue is whenever I am debugging the test and reaching the azure function, this code always returns 0,

```
int rows = _dataUpdater.UpdateDB(obj);
```

even though in my Mock setup I have asked to return 1. What could be issue, is there something I am missing?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `Setup(p => p.UpdateDB(It.IsAny<MyClass>())).Returns(1);`?

Comment: @AluanHaddad  You are probably right. But it depends. As currently written, the mock will return 1 if and only if UpdateDB is called with exactly the object `obj`.  Maybe that was even the intention?

Comment: @KlausGütter yeah, I was just guessing. Glad it worked though

Comment: someone should post this as the answer, get your internet points